# Batch file to copy specific folders

Tags: batch

This is the batch file i have created which copy the specific folders which I want. I use the specific server folder name of which I want to copy. Please suggest any improvements.

```
@echo off
:: variables
echo This script takes the backup of file SwiftALM Important folders
set /P source=Enter source folder Example D:\jboss6.1\server\swift:
set /P destination=Enter Destination folder:
set /P Folder=Enter Folder name:
@echo folder=%folder%
mkdir %destination%\%folder%
set xcopy=xcopy /E/V/Q/F/H/I 
echo echo conf folder will be copied
%xcopy% %source%\conf %destination%\%folder%\conf
echo conf folder is copied
echo lib folder will be copied
%xcopy% %source%\lib %destination%\%folder%\lib
echo lib folder is copied
echo deploy folder will be copied
%xcopy% %source%\deploy %destination%\%folder%\deploy
echo deploy folder is copied
echo deployers folder will be copied
%xcopy% %source%\deployers %destination%\%folder%\deployers 
echo deplyers folder is copied
echo files will be copy press enter to proceed
pause
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SETLOCAL` ensures that any environment variables you set don't affect the calling process's environment. It's like a sandbox for variables, directory changes, and other shell settings.

I usually use `@ECHO` instead of plain `ECHO`s so that if the `@ECHO OFF` is ever temporarily disabled (say, for debugging purposes), the echo statements don't produce needless noise in the output.

I also suggest using a loop to repeat the nearly-duplicate statements:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: variables
@ECHO This script takes the backup of file SwiftALM Important folders
SET /P source=Enter source folder Example D:\jboss6.1\server\swift:
SET /P destination=Enter Destination folder:
SET /P folder=Enter Folder name:

@ECHO folder=%folder%

MKDIR %destination%\%folder%
SET xcopy=xcopy /E/V/Q/F/H/I 

FOR /F %%s IN (conf lib deploy deployers) DO (
    echo %%s folder will be copied
    %xcopy% %source%\%%s %destination%\%folder%\%%s
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 @ECHO %%s folder has been copied.
)

@ECHO Files have been copied. Press enter to proceed.
PAUSE
```

Comment: Except `@ECHO OFF`, the `@` for the rest are unnecessary, right?

Comment: @janos Yes. I include them as the Proper Way to Do Things™ so that if you ever comment out `@ECHO OFF`, the `@ECHO` statements don't produce noisy output.

Comment: Interesting +1. It would be good to mention this in your post.

Answer (score 2):

Some minor improvements:

- It looks like you doubled `echo` in this command by mistake: `echo echo conf folder will be copied`
- It would be good to add some blank lines to separate related blocks and improve readability

With the above suggestions applied it becomes:

```
@echo off
:: variables
echo This script takes the backup of file SwiftALM Important folders
set /P source=Enter source folder Example D:\jboss6.1\server\swift:
set /P destination=Enter Destination folder:
set /P Folder=Enter Folder name:
set xcopy=xcopy /E/V/Q/F/H/I 

echo folder=%folder%
mkdir %destination%\%folder%

echo conf folder will be copied
%xcopy% %source%\conf %destination%\%folder%\conf
echo conf folder is copied

echo lib folder will be copied
%xcopy% %source%\lib %destination%\%folder%\lib
echo lib folder is copied

echo deploy folder will be copied
%xcopy% %source%\deploy %destination%\%folder%\deploy
echo deploy folder is copied

echo deployers folder will be copied
%xcopy% %source%\deployers %destination%\%folder%\deployers 
echo deplyers folder is copied

echo files will be copy press enter to proceed
pause
```

Comment: @VaibhavVeralkar Use a loop, too.